# Array output is duplicated

Tags: php

I have the following `Array` that I get from a `POST` operation in PHP:

```
Array ( 
    [level-1] => 3 
    [quarter-1] => 1 
    [year-1] => 2014 
    [level-2] => 4 
    [quarter-2] => 2 
    [year-2] => 2014 
    [level-53] => 2 
    [quarter-53] => 1 
    [year-53] => 2013 
    [level-58] => 3 
    [quarter-58] => 2 
    [year-58] => 2014 
    [action] => store 
    [submit_values] => Store 
)
```

I do the following operation to get values from the Array:

```
        $array=$_POST;
        foreach(array_chunk($array,3,true) as $val){
            foreach($val as $k=>$v){
               if(strpos($k, "level") !== false){
                 $temp    = explode("-",$k);
                 $id      = $temp[1];
                 $level   = $v;
                 }
             if(strpos($k, "quarter") !== false){
                 $quarter = $v;
             }
             if(strpos($k, "year") !== false){
                $year    = $v;
                }
            }
          echo "ID ".$id." Level ".$level." Quarter ".$quarter." Year ".$year;
          echo "<br>";
        }
```

But what I get is the following:

```
ID 1 Level 3 Quarter 1 Year 2014
ID 2 Level 4 Quarter 2 Year 2014
ID 53 Level 2 Quarter 1 Year 2013
ID 58 Level 3 Quarter 2 Year 2014
ID 58 Level 3 Quarter 2 Year 2014
```

With the last line duplicated! Anything I did wrong in my code?

Comment: If that's the output you _want_ to get, the code is right. But you don't tell us what you _want_, so we cannot tell you.

Comment: I do not want the last line to be duplicated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$array = $_POST;
unset($array['submit_values']);
unset($array['action']); //...
```

Answer (score 0):

You doesn't check for last loop with `action` and `submit_values`, so it returns **last saved values**:

```
$array=$_POST;
    foreach(array_chunk($array,3,true) as $val){
        foreach($val as $k=>$v){
           if(strpos($k, "level") !== false){
             $temp    = explode("-",$k);
             $id      = $temp[1];
             $level   = $v;
             }
         elseif(strpos($k, "quarter") !== false){
             $quarter = $v;
         }
         elseif(strpos($k, "year") !== false){
            $year    = $v;
         }
         // if not one of ifs works
         else continue;
        }
      echo "ID ".$id." Level ".$level." Quarter ".$quarter." Year ".$year;
      echo "<br>";
    }
```

Also always better to reset values after loop:

```
foreach(array_chunk($array,3,true) as $val){
    $id = '';
    $level = '';
    $quarter = '';
    $year = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

When the loop goes through **[action] = >store**  and **[submit_values] => Store** , the control doesnt enter into any if statement, hence during last 2 loops,it prints the previously set values

**i.e., ID 58 Level 3 Quarter 2 Year 2014**

**Solution:**

Try reinitializing **ID**, **Level**, **Quarter** and **Year** to ***" "(blank value)*** at end of foreach loop.